# Calculating expected value and variance of a probability density function

Tags: probability

If I was given a probability density function:

$$f(y) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{3y^2(4-y)}{64} & \textrm{for }  0 \leq y \leq 4\\
           0 & \textrm{elsewhere} \end{array}\right.$$

for expected value would that just be the following integral? 
$$\int_{0}^{4} yf(y)\,\textrm{d}y$$

I do not know how I would calculate the variance though. Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is fine for the expected value. Then find the expected value of $Y^2$ in similar fashion. Use the two expectations to get the variance.

Comment: @soakley would I have to change the y every time? so I would that formula 4 times because I have 1,2,3,4?

Comment: @user125627 You are evaluating a definite integral, so the probability distribution is continuous, not discrete (i.e. values can be 1.5, 2.78 etc)

Comment: @user130512 I am getting a little confusing because shouldn't the expected value be the sum of all the values, but wouldn't that mean I will have to change y multiple times?

Comment: The summation formula is only used for discrete random variables. You need to use integration. Look at the given answer.

Comment: @soakley maybe I am not understanding this correctly. I understand now you have to use the integral but how will I know which y value to use? Could I just use any y value and that will be enough? Which y value am I suppose to pick in order to find this expected value.

Comment: You need to use the variable $y,$ not a specific value. I will post it as an answer for the expected value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the expected value, you need to evaluate the integral $$\int_0^4 yf(y) dy =\int_0^4 {3y^3(4-y) \over 64} dy $$

Answer (score 9):

You can either find the variance directly by applying the [law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) with $g(y)=(y-{\rm E}[Y])^2$, that is,
$$
\mathrm{Var}(Y)={\rm E}[(Y-{\rm E}[Y])^2]=\int_0^4g(y)f(y)\,\mathrm dy,
$$
or you could find ${\rm E}[Y^2]$ by the same formula with $g(y)=y^2$ and then use that
$$
\mathrm{Var}(Y)={\rm E}[Y^2]-{\rm E}[Y]^2.
$$